# Converting ARM Template to Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm-template

Has anyone worked on converting the ARM template to Terraform file?

I understand that we can use "azurerm_template_deployment" resource in Terraform to deploy the ARM template but there are limitations and I am looking trying to find a way to directly convert ARM template to Terraform .tf file

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be converted directly, but terraform can deploy arm templates using the `azurerm_template_deployment` resource. When setting the deployment type to 'complete', TF should also destroy the resource!

See the following link for an example that destroying also works: https://samcogan.com/deploying-arm-templates-with-terraform/.

Comment: Do you mean when deployment type is set to 'complete', TF will destroy and recreate the resource(s) created by the ARM template everytime it's run?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any tools available to convert ARM template to TF. I have used "azurerm_template_deployment" and I'm happy about it. My case was limited though.

Refer this github issue for more details,
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1115

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "azurerm_template_deployment" is a great resource if we want to use the ARM template using Terraform, however, the resource is deployed using ARM template during destroy TF will not destroy the resource as it would not be recognized by TF.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check https://www.hcl2json.com/ if you want to convert between JSON and HCL (language used in TF)